Is there a way to avoid quaternion precision error?
I am trying to use quaternions to deal with 3D rotation.
I noticed that sometime I have small errors here and there. I am using Eigen as math library.
Here the shortest code that shows the issue:
struct Pose
{
    Eigen::Quaterniond rotation;
    Eigen::Vector3d position;

    explicit Pose(Eigen::Vector3d position);

    Pose(Eigen::Quaterniond rotation, Eigen::Vector3d position);

    Pose operator*(Pose p) const;

    static Pose identity();

    Pose inverse() const;
};

Pose::Pose(Eigen::Vector3d position) : rotation(Eigen::Quaterniond()),
                                       position(position) 
{
}

Pose::Pose(Eigen::Quaterniond rotation, Eigen::Vector3d position) : rotation(rotation),
                                                                    position(position)
{
}

Pose Pose::identity() 
{
    return Pose(Eigen::Quaterniond(), //
                Eigen::Vector3d(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
}

Pose Pose::operator*(Pose p) const 
{
    return Pose(rotation * p.rotation, // rotation
                (rotation * p.position) + position); // position
}

Pose Pose::inverse() const 
{
    const Eigen::Quaterniond qInv = (rotation.inverse());
    return Pose(qInv, qInv * (-position));
}


template<typename T>
static void testQuat() {
    Pose<T> parentGlobalLocation = Pose<T>::identity();

    Pose<T> childGlobalLocation = Pose<T>::identity();
    Pose<T> childLocalLocation = Pose<T>::identity();

    parentGlobalLocation.rotation = Eigen::AngleAxis<T>(45.0 * (EIGEN_PI / 180.0), Eigen::Vector3<T>(1, 0, 0));
    childGlobalLocation = parentGlobalLocation;
    Pose<T> shift = Pose<T>(Eigen::Quaternion<T>(1, 0, 0, 0), Eigen::Vector3<T>(0, 0, 10));

    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        childGlobalLocation = childGlobalLocation * shift;
        childLocalLocation = parentGlobalLocation.inverse() * childGlobalLocation;

        ++i;
        if (i % 10 == 0 || i == 1) {
            printf("iter %d [%.15lf, %.15lf, %.15lf]\n", i, childLocalLocation.position.x(),
                   childLocalLocation.position.y(), childLocalLocation.
                   position.z());
        }
    }
}

static void testMatrix() 
{
    Eigen::Matrix4d parentGlobalLocation;
    parentGlobalLocation.setIdentity();

    Eigen::Matrix4d childGlobalLocation;
    Eigen::Matrix4d childLocalLocation;
    childGlobalLocation.setIdentity();
    childLocalLocation.setIdentity();

    parentGlobalLocation.topLeftCorner(3, 3) = Eigen::AngleAxisd(45.0 * (EIGEN_PI / 180), Eigen::Vector3d(1, 0, 0)).
            toRotationMatrix();
    childGlobalLocation = parentGlobalLocation;

    Eigen::Matrix4d shift;
    shift.setIdentity();
    shift.block<3, 1>(0, 3) = Eigen::Vector3d(0, 0, 10000000);

    childGlobalLocation = childGlobalLocation * shift;
    childLocalLocation = parentGlobalLocation.inverse() * childGlobalLocation;

    Eigen::Vector3d pos = childLocalLocation.block<3, 1>(0, 3);
    printf("[%.3f, %.3f, %.3f]\n", pos.x(), pos.y(), pos.z());
}

int main() 
{
    testQuat<float>();
    testMatrix();
    return 0;
}

I also created the same code logic using the matrices instead of quaternion and the result is correct using the matrices.
The output when I use the quaternion is:
[0.000, -0.754, 10000000.000]

Instead when I use the matrix the output is:
[0.000, 0.000, 10000000.000]

The expected one is:
[0.000, 0.000, 10000000.000]

Do you have any hints?

Eigen::Quaterniond(0.923879564, 0.382683426, 0.0, 0.0) how did you come up with those numbers?

This is just a 45 degrees on Rx

45 degrees (pi/4 radians) or 45 radians? I ask because AFAIK eigen is radian based.
Do the errors show up after iterative calculations? If so try prevent those if you can (I hope you have heard about numerical methods and how errors can propagate in calculations)

Your magic numbers are lacking precision. double can typically hold ~16 decimal digits, but yo provide only 9. EIGEN_PI seems to be of high precision double value, promoting other simple constants to double. Use mathematical double expressions to build the initial constant values.

You can initialize an Eigen::Quaterniond by an Eigen::AngleAxisd object, instead of trying to hand-calculate the values.

What do you intend a Pose to represent?  I see a Quaternion and a Vector.  What that is supposed to mean, geometrically, matters to what the code is supposed to do.  And when you do PoseA*PoseB, do you intend for PoseA to be "first" then PoseB?  I think you might mean "translate by the vector.  Centered at this new locatoin, rotate by the rotation."?  If so, your construction order is strange.

Yep sorry, during all the tests I performed I forgot to remove the hard coded values.
However also using Eigen::AngleAxisd the error is still there:
For example after 700000 iterations using double precision I got
[0.000000000000000, -0.000036191195250, 7000000.000006018206477]
And if I try with float instead of double (that is how I started noticed this numerical issue) I have this result after 100 iterations
iter 100 [0.000000000000000, -0.000610351562500, 999.999145507812500]
So I was wondering if there is, and you can suggest, some method to correct this drift if possible

In this case Pose represents the position and orientation of an object

Small errors is kind of expected. Floating point (single or double precision) errors are expected since the representation is not exact. You have to expect small errors and compensate for them in your own code.

The code in your question does not match the test case you describe in comments. Please [edit] your question to show the 100, 700,000 iteration case you talk about

Yeah small errors are expected, can you point me out about some technique to compensate them?

At least normalize quternions after multiplications.

Eigen at some places assumes that the quaternions have unit length (e.g., when rotating a vector by a quaternion), but multiplying two unit-quaternions will almost always introduce some error. So at least occasionally normalizing the quaternions will remove that error. But if you accumulate small rotations, there will always be some drift from a "true" result -- to compensate for that you need some kind of absolute reference and use something like a Kalman-Filter.

Also, depending on your overall use-case Eigen::Transform/Eigen::Affine3d etc may or may not be better than Quaternion+Vector3 to represent a Pose (really depends on what operations you are doing)


Precision loss you described is expected. Always normalize quaternions when using "Eigen" library.

To optimize transformations multiplication of the form t1.inverse() * t2 in terms of precision, you can implement a custom function t1.inverseMul(t2).


rot_result = rot1.inverse()*rot2;
trans_result = rot_result*(trans2-trans1);


please use formatting to avoid code/math showing up broken. help page: [code block] -- you should describe your variables, which are q1, q2, qr, p1, p2, pr.
